# C++ Poco ODBC Transactions - AutoCommit mode

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, odbc, poco-libraries

I am currently attempting to use transactions in my C++ app, but I have a problem with the ODBC's auto commit mode.

I am using the POCO libaries to create a connection to a PostgreSQL database on the same machine. Currently, I can send data to this database as single statements, but I cannot get my head around how to use Poco's transaction libraries to be able to send this data more quickly.

As I have several thousand records to insert, and so continuing to use single insert statements is extrememly slow and inpractical - So I am trying to use Poco's transaction to speed this up a bit (a fair bit).

The error I am encountering is a theoretically a simple one - Poco is throwing the following error:

```
'Invalid access: Session is in auto commit mode.'
```

I understand, as a result of this, I should somehow set "auto commit" to false - as it only allows me to commit data to the database line by line, rather than as a single transaction.

The problem is how I set this.

Currently, I have a session created from Session.h, that looks alot like this:

```
 session = new Poco::Data::Session(
                "ODBC",
                connection_data.str()
            );
```

Where connection data is a simple stringstream with the login information, password, database, server and "Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};" to tell ODBC to utilize PostgreSQL's driver.

I have tried just setting a property "autocommit" to false through the session's setFeature or setProperty settings, this, of course, was to no avail. (it was more of a ditch attempt at this point).

```
   session->setFeature("AUTOCOMMIT", false);
```

Looking around, I saw a possible alternative method by creating a ODBC sessionImpl directly from ODBC/session/SessionImpl.h instead of using this generic method above, and then creating a new session object from this.

The benefits of this are that ODBC's sessionImpl has references to autocommit mode in the header, which would suggest it would be able to handle this:

```
void autoCommit(const std::string&, bool val);
    /// Sets autocommit property for the session.
```

However, having not used sessionImpl before, I cannot garuntee if this will work or if can can get this to work with the limited documentation available.

I am using C++ 03 (Not 11), with Visual Studio 2015
Poco 1.7.5
Boost (Where needed)

> Would any one know the correct way of setting this feature (above) or a alternative method to achieving this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

edit: Looking at the source of poco, at:

https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Data/ODBC/src/SessionImpl.cpp#L153

The property seems be named `autoCommit`, and looking at

https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Data/include/Poco/Data/AbstractSessionImpl.h#L120

the case of the property names seem to matter. So, does it help if you use  `session->setFeature("autoCommit", false);`?

---

Cant you just call `session->begin();` and `session->end();` on the corresponding Session object?

What is returned by `session->canTransact()`?

According to the doc `begin()` will start a new transaction, the doc does not mention any property that needs to be set before or after.

See: https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Data.Session.html

Comment: Yes, I can call session->begin(), but it will also throw 'Invalid access: Session is in auto commit mode.' aswell. - The result of canTransact() is 1, I tried using this to guard the session->begin().

Comment: Sorry, did not get that from your question. I guess you then also already tried using the Poco Transaction class?

Comment: You are correct, I have also tried creating a Poco transaction class. I am currently attempting to directly create an ODBC SessionImpl object myself, and try to get around it that way.

Comment: @Chris: I have updated my answer, browsing through the poco source shows that the property is named "autoCommit" - doesnt help either?

Answer (score 0):

Also faced a similar issue.
First of all before begin() need:

```
m_ses.setFeature("autoCommit", false);
m_ses.begin();
```

And the second issue is that this feature stays "autoCommit" in false for all other sessions. So don't forget for the next session call

```
session.setFeature("autoCommit", true);
```